# Is it safe to send authorization header from a server to client?

Tags: security, http, https, basic-authentication

I'm setting up a new app. Everything is through non-HTTPS. Just HTTP. Anyway, after the user logs in the server sends the client a nice 200, and this:

```
{
"user": {
    "_id": "5595bb294cbed176e7594e79",
    "username": "ckent1000",
    "email": "clarkcando@gmail.com",
    "roles": {
        "account": {
            "id": "5597089bbde23bf2179dba46",
            "name": "superman"
        }
    }
},
"session": {
    "userId": "5595bb294cbed176e7594e79",
    "key": "6c5c2ed4-77f9-4038-b175-e9fb927c1b22",
    "time": "2015-07-06T14:31:58.175Z",
    "_id": "559a915e53723a85eaf75ea9"
},
"authHeader": "Basic NTU5YTkxNWU1MzcyM2E4NWVhZjc1ZWE5OjZjNWMyZWQ0LTc3ZjktNDAzOC1iMTc1LWU5ZmI5MjdjMWIyMg=="
```

}

Is that cool? My sage wisdom suggests that it's not because this is over HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP basic authentication transports credentials *in the clear* (i.e. readable by anyone who can access the packets, in transit or later).  They are Base-64 encoded for transport, but this provides **no confidentiality**.

You **must** secure your communications with TLS if you plan to use Basic authentication.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication for more information.

Comment: So what you're saying, "No, it's encrypted so you have that but... send it over SSL anyway!"?

Comment: Base-64 **is not encryption**.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm glad you told me. I need to go to Google more that was almost a bad question. Thx doods.